# FFmpeg AVI recording for H264 @ 1fps not working

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, vlc

I am recording H.264 (640x480 @1fps 10seconds) in avi container using FFMPEG. When I play the recorded file in VLC, it plays only first frame and rest of the frames are not played. I am getting

> main warning: late picture skipped (555293 > -305)

Output of ffprobe is:

```
FFprobe version 0.6.2-4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1~ppa1~lucid1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010 the Libav developers
  built on Jan  3 2012 18:16:35 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: --extra-version='4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1~ppa1~lucid1' --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[h264 @ 0x9feb230]insane cropping not completely supported, this could look slightly wrong ...
[avi @ 0x9fea010]max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, avi, from 'h2641fps.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf52.7.0
  Duration: 00:00:11.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 95 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1 fps, 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 60 tbc
[h264 @ 0x9feb230]insane cropping not completely supported, this could look slightly wrong ...
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/60
codec_tag_string=H264
codec_tag=0x34363248
width=640
height=480
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=4:3
pix_fmt=yuv420p
r_frame_rate=1/1
avg_frame_rate=1/1
time_base=1/1
start_time=0:00:00.000000
duration=0:00:11.000000
nb_frames=11
[/STREAM]
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Same code works perfectly for frame rate above 3

Comment: any pointers will be appreciated..

Comment: @Alam What command line did you use?

Comment: @Dmitry, yes I can play using ffplay. I can also play using AVIdemux. But VLC is unable to play

Comment: @satuon: I am capturing frames directly from camera and using av_write_frame(oc, &pkt); for writing frames. c->time_base.den = frame_rate * 100;  c->time_base.num = 100;. I am not setting any pts or dts value.

Comment: @Alam AVI should not be used with H.264 if b-frames are used.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: As frame rate is 1, so all frames are I frame. The output of ffprobe has has_b_frames=0. Anyways I would like to know why I cant use H.264 b frames in AVI? Is this related with dts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question, It may help someone having similar issues:

VLC plays streams when I increase cache size from 300ms to 900ms. I am not sure if its a correct method or not. As avi header is having information of framerate, VLC should wait for atleast 900 or 1000ms for next frame. "late picture skipped" should come after 1000ms.